# how to deleted item materialize chips

Tags: jquery, materialize

I want to let me know when I delete one of the items or ask for confirm before deleting

```
$('.chips.the-best').chips({
    onChipDelete:function(){
     cosnole.log('deleted item')   
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

file: materialize.js line 8150

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // Handle removal of static chips.
    $(document.body).on('click', '.chip .close', function () {  
      var $chips = $(this).closest('.chips');
      if ($chips.length && $chips[0].M_Chips) {
        return;
      }
      $(this).closest('.chip').remove();

    });
  });
```